# Contracts/Requests - last commitment

Tags: sql, oracle

Customer service contracts with additional requests

I have the following relation among tables:

```
[Contracts] 0,n--> [CR] <--n [Requests]
```

Where one contract can have zero or more (additional) requests. Both contracts and requests tables do have COMMITMENT_START_DATE and COMMITMENT_END_DATE columns defining the start and end dates of contract commitment. The latest defined contract commitment (obligation) in contract or additional request is the relevant one.

For example customer has a main contract with commitment from 1.1.2021 to 1.1.2022 and later takes additional request with commitment from 1.3.2021 to 1.3.2022 - then the last customer commitment date is 1.3.2022 (from additional request).

Also if customer has a main contract with commitment from 1.1.2022 to 1.1.2023 and later takes additional request with commitment from 1.3.2022 to 1.9.2022 - the last commitment date is 1.1.2023 (from main contract).

Both contracts and request could be without commitment.

I need the SQL which will list all contracts with information if they have the commitment / what is the (last) end date of commitment.

Comment: So you need to do a left join and a case statement to evaluate which date (if one or more exists ) is greater and then get the max of that grouped by your contract?  (Table, sample data expected results always a plus)  Your existing example is confusing because you say you need the latest: define a range of 1.1.2021 to 1.1.2022 with a request of 1.3.2021 and claim it's greater than 1.1.2022... So I don't understand what you're after.

Comment: Are you sure that dates you posted in the 1st example are correct? Additional request from 1.3.2021 to 1.3.2021? Only one day?

Comment: @Littlefoot I edited, you were right

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `CR#` is the common key between Contracts and Requests:

```
SELECT CR#, MAX(COMMITMENT_END_DATE)
  FROM (SELECT CR#, COMMITMENT_END_DATE
          FROM CONTRACTS
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CR#, COMMITMENT_END_DATE
          FROM REQUESTS)
  GROUP BY CR#
```